# Seeking GIS SE Marketing Materials?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed

Are there any marketing materials for GIS SE?

I am helping set up an OSGEO booth at [GIS In Action](http://www.orurisa.org/GIS_In_Action) in Portland OR and I would like to have a simple single sheet flyer which explains what GIS SE is all about.  GIS In Action is a regional conference which hosts around 150 industry professionals from the Oregon and SW Washington area.

Maybe there is a flyer for Stack Overflow that we could adapt?

Comment: I distributed some StackExchange t-shirts at the Esri Dev Summit.  They were nice, but I think it would be even better to have Gis as part of the design.  It would be great if the artist who created the web site design could also design a matching t-shirt.

Comment: Here's a related request/suggestion on MetaSO (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77556/dont-you-think-that-its-time-for-some-stack-exchange-shirts). Doesn't look like anything is ready yet.

Comment: All right, great to see a GIS.SE t-shirt.  Would be nice to have one with the faded map background (like the web site design) in addition to black.  The black model may be comfortable in NYC, but for those of us in warmer climes a low-albedo model would be appreciated.

Comment: correction: _high_ albedo model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We do indeed have a one-page flyer ready now, if anyone needs one in the future.

We've placed [the one-page GIS flyer in Google Docs as a public PDF](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0B8LiGj-DooyVOGFhNTFlZTMtMzk5Ni00Yzg2LWE5ZDctMWVmOTlkN2YzNTZh&hl=en_US), for anyone who wants it. Once the page loads, use the File menu in the upper left to select "Download Original".

Comment: How do I go about getting a copy of that?

Comment: @michael it's available now, sorry for the delay

Comment: To you mind if I use [mine](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/511/flyer-for-esri-conference-2011) as well? I'll stagger both of them as widely as possible.

Comment: Cool!  It is conference time again in my area, so I will be making use of the flyers.

Answer (score 5):

you can use GIS.se site header logo image for any print material you're making. Just save the image below.

[image: GIS.se header logo]

Also feel free to use the Stack Exchange logo in the footer, tiny size is fine. You can download the stack exchange logo at http://stackexchange.com/about/logos